# Saving Vectors In Java

Tags: java

How would I go about saving a String Vector to a file every time it is edited?

So let's say I have usernames in a vector, after I add or delete a username I'd like it to save that vector so if the program is closed, it will show the most recent elements.

Comment: I'd wrap the vector in a class, as a private member variable. You can then expose public functions like "add(String userName)" and "remove(String userName)" 
These functions would add to the vector and also persist the vector to file.
You then have the flexibility to change your vector to another collection type as appropriate. (For example, you may only want unique user names and use a Set)

Comment: @jazeee Honestly I'm still a beginner and not familiar with using wrappers. Just did some research and wrappers are used to make primitive types visible as objects is that correct? How would these functions be called if vector is private variable within the wrapper? It is a String Vector and string is a primitive type so I can see how wrapping could work. But I don't fully understand the concept of the wrapper. Maybe I need to try to understand OO better.

Comment: wrapping, in this context, simply means making the vector (you should use an ArrayList, BTW) a private field of a class that would expose add() and remove() methods. Those methods would add/remove to the vector AND write the vector to the file.

Comment: @user402442 you should make that an answer, and provide some pseudo-code to help the OP getting started.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you get started.
As JB Nizet said, you should use an ArrayList.
I also went ahead and used Java 7 autocloseable functionality, which ensures you close file handles appropriately.

Of course, you will need to validate your input, and you will want to take care about what you persist.  I suspect that you will soon want to consider a better storage strategy, however, this will get you started.

In addition, since this is acting like a collection, you should add hashcode and equals.  For brevity sake, I did not add those.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PersistedCollection {
    private static final String NEWLINE_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private final List<String> values;
    private final File file;

    public PersistedCollection(File file) {
        this.values = new ArrayList<>();
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void add(String value) {
        // You should validate this value. Remove carriage returns, make sure it meets your value specifications.
        values.add(value);
        persist();
    }

    public void remove(String value) {
        values.remove(value);
        persist();
    }

    private void persist() {
        // Using Java 7 autocloseable to ensure that the output stream is closed, even in exceptional circumstances.
        try (OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(this.file), 8192); Writer writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream)) {
            for (String value : values) {
                writer.append(value);
                writer.append(NEWLINE_SEPARATOR);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("PersistedCollection [values=");
        builder.append(values);
        builder.append(", file=");
        builder.append(file);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        PersistedCollection persistedCollection = new PersistedCollection(new File("/tmp/test.txt"));
        persistedCollection.add("jazeee");
        persistedCollection.add("temporary user");
        persistedCollection.add("user402442");
        persistedCollection.add("JB Nizet");
        persistedCollection.remove("temporary user");
        System.out.println(persistedCollection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to create a class where you add all the methods required to read from a file of usernames (one username per line). Then you can refer to this class from anywhere (as the modifier is public) and call the methods such that you will add or remove usernames from that file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;

public class Test {

private static BufferedWriter bw;
private static ArrayList<String> vector=new ArrayList<String>();
private static String everything;

//add an username
public static void add(String x){
    vector.add(x);
}
//remove an username
public static void remove(String x){
    vector.remove(x);
}

//update the file with the new vector of usernames
public static void updateToFile() throws IOException{
    File username = new File("/home/path/to/the/file");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(username.getAbsoluteFile());
    bw= new BufferedWriter(fw); 
for (String x:vector){
    bw.write(x.toString());     
    bw.write("\n");
    }
bw.close();
}

//you call this method to initialise your vector of usernames
//this implies that you already have a file of usernames
//one username per line
public static void setUsername() throws IOException{
    vector=new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/path/to/the/file"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        everything = sb.toString();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    String lines[] = everything.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String x:lines){
        vector.add(x);
    }

}

//print your usernames in the console
public static void printUsers(){
    for (String User:vector){
        System.out.println(User);
    }
}
}
```

Then it gets as easy as this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainTest {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
     Test.setUsername();
     Test.printUsers();
     Test.add("username5");
     Test.remove("username2");
     System.out.println("// add username5; remove username2");
     Test.printUsers();
     System.out.println("// file has been updated with the new state");
     Test.updateToFile();
     System.out.println("// veryfing update");
     Test.setUsername();
     Test.printUsers();


 }
}
```

The output:
(this first 4 users is what I have in the file)

```
    username1
    username2
    username3
    username4
    // add username5; remove username2
    username1
    username3
    username4
    username5
    // file has been updated with the new state
    // verifying update
    username1
    username3
    username4
    username5
```

Comment: I would not recommend using static member variables like this. It is bad practice.  For example, if I created two instances of Test, I would not be able to use them as expected.

Comment: I would definitely change my code accordingly. If one has multiple threads which need to instantiate the Test class and to concurrently read/write to the file you are most likely right.